# .h files are ending up in the "compile sources" of the build phase in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to objective c and going through some books to learn it.

The applications I create for the sample applications give me a compiler warning: warning: no rule to process file... Through some googling, I found that the problem is that the file it's trying to process is in the Compile Sources window of the Build Phase. When I remove the .h file, the warning goes away.

My question is, how is it getting in there? I haven't been able to narrow down if it happens every single time, but in my current application, if I add a new Objective C class, it will automatically place the .h file in the Compile Sources window. So I'm wondering if anyone can tell me why that might be happening and how I can stop it. Thanks so much everyone.

EDIT: I just restarted XCode and it no longer adds the .h and .m files together to the Compile Sources window (it only adds the .m file).

Answer (score 1):

> Just select "add to project" from my Xcode menu for new .m and .h files, check add to target, and the then they compile and link when Build for my iPhone target.

OR

> Check what the path is relative to (open the ‘File Inspector’). May be you were migrating files and accidentally they got marked as ‘relative to group’, and this caused files not to be found by the compiler. Heck, this is rather confusing for me as well.

Comment: Hi there...thanks for the response. If I'm understanding you correctly, then that would help if I was importing files into a current project. My problem is that this happens when I need to create a new class for my project. I was wondering if maybe there was a setting somewhere in the project compiler settings that is placing the new .h file in the Build Phase. I'm just so new to all this that I don't know where to check =)

Comment: Please check my updated answer. hope it resolve your confusion.

Comment: Yeah...I'm still not sure what is happening. Just got into a new chapter in my book and started up a new project. Every time I create a new class, both the .h and .m files get put in the Compile Sources window under the Build Phases tab. This time I ended up deleting the original project I created and started a new one, but the same thing happened. Then I restarted xcode, added a new class, and everything's just right - only the .m file was placed in the Compile Sources window. I don't get it???